# Fixing Nested aggregated function

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to display the productid for the product that has been sold the most (i.e, that has been sold in the highest quantity)

I have tried multiple different versions of code but every time it says cannot nest aggregated operations

```sql
SELECT productid
FROM soldvia 
GROUP BY productid
WHERE productid IN (SELECT MAX(SUM(noofitems)) FROM soldvia GROUP BY productid);
```

I expect the output to be 
PRODUCTID
3x3
4x4

Comment: Use order by instead of group by or where?

Comment: It says "more than one value was returned by subquery.

Comment: please see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/58087902/7089274, It is working and running query. no error in my query. will help you.

Comment: What if there are ties?

Answer (score 4):

You can't nest aggregations.
Use `ORDER BY` with `TOP` :

```
SELECT TOP 1 productid 
FROM soldvia 
GROUP BY productid
ORDER BY SUM(noofitems) DESC
```

Comment: I tried this and it said "Syntax error: expected something between the 'DESC' keyword and the 'LIMIT' keyword."

Comment: The query is syntactically correct. Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vcyvFbZ14EZD9xgpqzbqL4/0 So you did not use the code correctly.

Comment: @mmcnutt is there a case that you are using Teradata and not MySQL?

Comment: I am using teradata.

Comment: @mmcnutt if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark at the left

Answer (score 1):

Please try below query for your exact answer.

```
 select productid, sum(noofitems) as max_sold, 

 convert(varchar,productid) +' x '+ convert(varchar,sum(noofitems)) as

 output_sold from soldvia group by productid order by sum(noofitems) desc
```

Output will be

```
 ProductId  NoOfItemSold  Output_Sold
  1          7               1x7
  2          4               2x4
  3          1               3x1
```

Answer (score 1):

In Teradata, you can use the [`qualify`](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/2_MC9vCtAJRlKle2Rpb0mA/19NnI91neorAi7LX6SJXBw) clause:

```
SELECT productid
FROM soldvia 
GROUP BY productid
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) = 1;
```

This is handy.  You can get duplicates by changing `ROW_NUMBER()` to `RANK()`.  Actually, `RANK()` is more consistent with the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @forpas is probably the way to go but this one is a little closer to yours:

```
SELECT productid
FROM soldvia
GROUP BY productid
HAVING SUM(noofitems) = (
        SELECT MAX(items)
        FROM (
            SELECT SUM(noofitems) AS items
            FROM soldvia
            GROUP BY productid
            ) x
        )
```